# how to build paypal refund url?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

how to do refund paypal amount using URL.
we not like to take any username and password from user that why we not expected to use any API.

we are expecting to build URL and user will click on that link and payapl take all refund responsibility and send us IPN message same flow the way donation button works..

we are able to take donation using below url.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?amount=10.00&bn=test&business=XXXX@.com&charset=utf-8&cmd=_donations&currency_code=USD&email=XWXXX@gmail.com&invoice=189&item_name=Production+move&no_shipping=1&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpaypal_ipns&return=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fthank-you%3Fdid%3DMTg5

iS their any way to build refund url?
we not able to found any source to build refund URL can some one help us....

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. You have to login to the paypal panel and use that instead

Comment: PayPal don't have that kind of URL yet. To refund, merchant must login to the account and initiate it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to implement an URL like this without APIs, also, refund is not supposed to be a "self-service" for the payers, as any funding reversal should be initialed/authoried by your account, either from website backend (with API) or in the transaction dashboard of your PP account